# Kotlin - Making it mutable in foreach

Tags: kotlin, foreach

So I've come to learn that the `it` in my foreach loop is immutable - namely I get the error `val cannot be reassigned`.

```
results.forEach{
            val subGenreNames = subGenreNames(it.subGenres)
            it.subGenres = subGenreNames
}
```

However I want to be able to update its value after I pass it into my `subGenreNames` function.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What type is `it`? Is `subGenres` a `val`?

Comment: `it` is of my own type - `Song` - ahh, and yes, within that `subGenres` was set a val. I updated it to be a var and it worked.

Comment: Awesome, you're good to go then!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you want to mutate `subGenres` rather than create new list with updated values? The more Kotlin way would be

```
val withSubGenreNames = results.map {
            it.copy(subGenres = subGenreNames(it.subGenres))
}
```

where `copy` is magical method if your `it` is `data class`.

This way you'd keep old list unchanged. You can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34385243/why-is-immutability-so-important-or-needed-in-javascript) why immutability is generally a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

Your quation was answered in the comments by [@Egor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/543539/egor), so I will just post the answer for you to resolve:

The `it` in the labda is immutable but the actual setter accesses inner field `subGenres`, which I guess is a `val`. Change `subGenres` to a `var`.