# Javascript: for-statement not processing all elements in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I have an array with various paragraphs inside:

```
var content = [ "<p>This is a paragraph 1</p>", 
                "<p>This is a paragraph 2</p>", 
                "<p>This is a paragraph 3</p>", 
                "<p>This is a paragraph 4</p>", 
                "<p>This is a paragraph 5</p>" ]
```

I want to perform a simple operation on each element inside the array. Each paragraph needs to be placed inside a container and then be removed from the array. 
This is the corresponding HTML:

```
<div class="article">
  <div id="cell1" class="text-block">
    <div class="container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is how I am attempting to do what I describe above:

```
for (i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
  console.log("Current item: " + content[i])
  //
  var itemtoRemove = content[i];
    $("#cell1 .container").append(content[i]);
  //
  content.splice($.inArray(itemtoRemove, content), 1)
}
```

I have put everything together in a fiddle as well: https://jsfiddle.net/johschmoll/1mjzu4qg/71/

Basically, everything is working fine, but the for-statement seems to be skipping every second element in the array. I cannot figure out the reason, even after looking at similar cases. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you are going to manipulate the array while looping over it, you need to start at the `length - 1` index and move backwards.  Because once you remove the first element and your `i` adjusts to 1, you're effectively looking at originally the 3rd element

Comment: `Array#splice` mutates the original array. Could it be that?

Comment: `content.splice` modifies the array while you're looping over it.

Comment: Otherwise, switch away from a for loop and use a `while (content.length)` loop

Comment: Why not use a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Comment: Also make sure `i` is declared with `let` or `var`

Comment: @Taplar Thanks, I was blind to that logic, it makes perfect sense

Comment: As a best practice, do not change the thing you are iterating on. Build a new array while iterating on the original one. It will certainly be easier to maintain/get what's happening instead of shifting indices.

Comment: @sjahan Thanks for the reply, can you explain why this is the best practice?

Comment: Because of the issue you just ran into, :)

Comment: @JoSch Immutability is often a good thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34385243/why-is-immutability-so-important-or-needed-in-javascript. If you want to change something, you create another thing and use it elsewhere. That way, you make sure that the data won't move without you are aware of it. It is often easier to understand, handle and maintain for your teammates later too! About iteration, some language would prevent you to modify the collection as it breaks the basis you are iterating, it is often a bad practice. You can edit an item, but not its order inside the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are modifying the array as you loop, use a while loop that checks that the array is not empty

```
while (content.length) {
  console.log("Current item: " + content[0])
  //
  var itemtoRemove = content[0];
    $("#cell1 .container").append(content[0]);
  //
  content.shift();
}
```

**Keeping in mind that if all you are doing is appending all the elements, then this is unnecessary.  `append()` can accept an array**

```
$("#cell1 .container").append(content.splice(0));
```

Comment: Regarding your note: Well, I am only appending, but it is important that the appended elements get removed from the array

Comment: So, append with the array and then set the array to an empty array.  Two operations

Comment: I should explain the context in which I'm using this: I'm working on a script that places paragraphs into a container until this container is "full", all paragraphs that do not fit get put into a separate container. That is why I need to modify the array. See here: https://jsfiddle.net/johschmoll/1mjzu4qg/96/

Happy about any and all advice on this.

Comment: Ok, so in your example there, you are not simply appending the elements.  You are conditionally appending the elements to different things.  That's a different use case.  The only thing I would say about that snippet is to point out the usage of `shift()` rather than `splice()`

Comment: Yeah, thanks for pointing it out. `shift()` was new for me, always a pleasure learning something new.

Answer (score 1):

Because you are modifying the array upon each iteration, the length of the array changes and you wind up skipping items. Instead, loop through the array backwards to avoid the issue.

```js
var content = [ "<p>This is a paragraph 1</p>", 
                "<p>This is a paragraph 2</p>", 
                "<p>This is a paragraph 3</p>", 
                "<p>This is a paragraph 4</p>", 
                "<p>This is a paragraph 5</p>" ]

for (var i = content.length-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
  console.log("Current item: " + content[i])

  var itemtoRemove = content[i];
  $("#cell1 .container").append(content[i]);

  content.splice($.inArray(itemtoRemove, content), 1)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="article">
  <div id="cell1" class="text-block">
    <div class="container"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```